# How can I parameterize ehcache.xml with properties loaded at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

I am using Ehcache + Hibernate + Spring with an ehcache.xml file. I would like to parameterize ehcache.xml with stuff from a properties file at runtime. Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what sort of config you're talking about. `ehcache.xml` contains some global config (e.g. the location of the disk-overflow directory), as well as cache-specific config.

If you're talking about the latter, then you can use Spring's EhCache support (i.e. `EhCacheFactoryBean` and `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean`) to configure and manage EhCache instances.

If you're talking about the global config, though, I don't there's a way.

Comment: I just want to fiddle the max size of the cache regions for some of the objects in my domain model (e.g. maxElementsInMemory="${some.property}). It seems like Ehcache is created by Hibernate. So for your suggestion I would need to get Hibernate to use my Spring configured Ehcache instead.